Conservation of Momentum in Isoscalar Dipole Vibration
I am reading chapter 6 of Introductory Nuclear Physics by Wong. He describes various low-order vibrational modes that the nucleus can take in an excited state, and includes a figure. I am confused how the isoscalar dipole mode is conserving momentum in its vibration. By the figure Wong provides, the center of mass of the nucleus seems to oscillate. How is this possible? Or am I misunderstanding the figure? 
This figure is located on page 206, 2nd edition.
